# How to add a usercontrol wpf window as status bar at the top of my windows used in my application when it get focus

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I am writing an application in which i need to implement a window at the top of all my window how can i do help me the window to be added is an usercontrol .how to add when the window gets focused i need to add this usercontrol window to it,
I wrote window loaded event for all the windows but its not fine .need some help

instead of adding it in wpf XAML code .

this is the common usercontrol code which comes in all windows.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Cutting_Machine.CutMACStatus"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="70"  d:DesignWidth="800" Background="SteelBlue">
    <Grid>
        <Label />
        <Label Name="lblstatus" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="22" Margin="5,0,560,42" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"  Foreground="Yellow" FontWeight="ExtraBold" Height="38">HOME</Label>
        <Label Margin="10,43,635,10"  FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiBold" Foreground="Yellow" Name="lbldate"/>
        <Label Margin="245,10,392,0" Name="lblposition" Foreground="Yellow" FontSize="36" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontWeight="ExtraBlack" Height="54" VerticalAlignment="Top" >1027.00</Label>
        <Label Margin="0,22,298,10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="80" Name="lblunits" BorderBrush="Black"  Foreground="Yellow" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" FontSize="24" VerticalContentAlignment="Top">mm</Label>
        <Label Margin="554,10,133,37" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Yellow" Name="lblmodel" ></Label>
        <Label Background="ForestGreen" Margin="554,53,218,6" FontSize="10" FontWeight="SemiBold" Foreground="White" Name="lblhw">HW</Label>
        <Label  FontSize="16" FontWeight="SemiBold" Foreground="Yellow" Margin="596,43,133,0" Name="lblcuts">Cuts</Label>
        <Label Background="SteelBlue" FontSize="18" FontWeight="SemiBold" Foreground="Yellow" Margin="674,10,70,5">Knife</Label>

        <Label Background="SteelBlue" FontSize="18" FontWeight="SemiBold" Foreground="Yellow" Margin="737,10,10,5" Name="lblhelp">Help</Label>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

i want this ui to be added to all windows when the windows got focus.

Comment: do add some example or piece of code what you've tried.

Comment: i made some chages in the question above see it

Comment: is it possible for you to share a screen of what you expect to see? are you trying to print some kind of report?

Comment: its enough to share that window in top of every window thats it

Answer (score 0):

With so far I understand from your question you want this control to appear on all of your windows when active

so start by defining a style in App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="Cutting_Machine.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="CutMACStatusStyle"
               TargetType="{x:Type Window}"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Window}}"
               xmlns:cm="clr-namespace:Cutting_Machine">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Window">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.Resources>
                                    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
                                </Grid.Resources>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <cm:CutMACStatus Visibility="{TemplateBinding IsActive, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                                <Border Grid.Row="1"
                                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}"
                                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                    <ContentPresenter />
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

the trick is to create a template with the status in a grid on top and actual content of the window at bottom

then all those window you want to have this header you specify style attribute for the same

```
<Window x:Class="Cutting_Machine.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Style="{StaticResource CutMACStatusStyle}">
```

this will show the user control on top of the window whenever the window is active

result

[image: active window]
active window

[image: inactive window]
inactive window

Comment: This i did already but the task is many window are there in which i need to add this in which event i should write this i wrote in windows loaded event is this is correct or else something else to be done

Comment: You simply have to add `Style="{StaticResource CutMACStatusStyle}"` in all of your windows where you want it to appear. you do not need to do in loaded or any other event.

Comment: thats fine depending upon the window i change in application the status bar lbl(1027) should chage different value for different window how to do it

Comment: where this value will come from? anyhow you can make use of binding in the user control to retrieve the value. is it possible for you to share a sample app so we both can see the same?